# Disable data checking while importing, and check after?

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I have a problem reimporting data with fields that depend on each other with heavy references, OneToMany, ManyToOne etc. If I try to persist an imported composition list I get:

```
object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: Foo.value -> Bar
```

I can remember Hibernate has some ?properties? to first import the whole bunch of data, and THEN after check if transients or fields could not be resolved.
But I do not find the reference any more for this.
Maybe someone knows of what I'm talking here?

tyvm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you will get transient exception in hibernate, it means that some object is saved. As per your comment what i guess is you have many-to-one relationship of bar with foo. There are 2 ways to solve this exception:

1. You need to save Bar object first and then save Foo.
2. hibernate provides cascade option. So, if you give cascade = "save-update" in many-to-one relation of Bar, at that when you save object hibernate will also save Bar if it is not saved.